# How to limit the amount of cache on the server

Tags: bolt-cms

I recently had an issue with a server filling up with > 400MB of Bolt Cache. (That is: after I emptied the cache, this amount of storage became available so I guess that that was the problem).

How can I prevent this without diving into cronjob stuff - which is a bit too geeky for me?

And could this have had something to do with the Tagcloud extension that I used on this site?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to limit the growth of the cache by configuration parameter.  However the weekly Bolt cron job does flush the cache...  Unfortunately you've got that in the "too geeky" pile, which is fair enough :-)

As for TagCloud, I have only installed it to fix a couple of bugs in it for someone else, so am not sure.  My guess would be you have a lot of images, and the generated thumbnails are what are taking up the space.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware that there is a 'weekly flush' by default, good to know hat. 

The current amount of used disk space looks OK (80MB in total as we speak), I'll keep an eye on that and only if it gets out of hand again I'll let you know.

Comment: Cool. Just one point in the interests of clarity, Bolt's cron needs to be set up to be called by the system cron...  There are docs at http://docs.bolt.cm and I would link them directly but am in a meeting and on my iPad :-)